# How do I set a firestore Timestamp from a custom Object?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a custom object called `myData`, and within that object I have a timestamp. Considering that the Node driver for Firebase doesn't support custom Objects, I'm quickly converting the data to pure JSON using the following line:

```
const dataAsJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myData));
```

However, when it does this it strips out the Date from the object and turns it into a string (if it is initially of type `Date`), or a map if it is of type `FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp`.

I suppose I could shoot another direct set on the same object right after with `const res = await docRef.set(data, {merge: true});` if `data = {dateExample: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('December 10, 1815'))}` but I'd rather do it all in one go.

Has anyone solved this before? I'm fear if I mess with a batch commit I may not be able to choose which gets set first.

Comment: *"the Node driver for Firebase doesn't support custom Objects"* - how did you come to this conclusion?  You can defeintely pass a plain JavaScript/TypeScript object to Firestore.  It will create fields and values in the document based on the properties in the object.

Comment: @DougStevenson I guess meant objects with a custom prototype. The error I get back is ```Value for argument data is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type... Firestore doesn't support objects with custom prototypes```. Perhaps there's a simple way for me to convert my custom prototype to a format Firestore does accept. Looking into that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stringifying then parsing your data will obviously destroy types of dates and timestamps in the object.  Those need to remain intact in order to be recognized by Firestore.

You will have to provide a plain JavaScript object representation of the object you want to store.  This could be as simple as just copying the properties into a new object based on the original object.  You will need to provide JavaScript Date or Firestore Timestamp objects in order to get a proper timestamp type in the document.  Same for reference types.

Since we can't see the object you're trying to serialize, I can give no specific advice, but it should be clear by now what you need to do.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I did. Here's the final code that works so far: ```const myCustomObj = new Object({hello: 1, date: Timestamp})
  const dataAsJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myCustomObj));
  dataAsJson.date = myCustomObj.date;```